# /var/run/postgres keeps being deleted, preventing postgres from starting

Tags: services, postgresql, sockets

By default, my PostgreSQL installation was creating a socket in `/tmp` but my `psql` command-line client was looking in `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`.

To remedy this, I edited `postgresql.conf` and changed the directory to

```
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql/'
```

Unfortunately, there is by default, no `postgresql` directory in the `var/run` directory. So, I created it and started the server, and it all worked well. As soon as I shutdown and restart the server, for some reason the `/var/run/postgresql` directory disappears. This causes the startup of postgres to crash with an error:

`FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory`

Help appreciated!

Comment: `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run`, where files (mainly PID files and lock files) are created on the fly. If you want a permanent location for the PID file, put it somewhere else, like `/var/postgres-socket/` or something.

Comment: @Jos, thanks for the comment. How do I get the `psql` client to look there?

Comment: I believe `psql -h /var/postgres-socket/` should work.  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html.

Comment: @Jos, I still think there is a better way, but your way is working, and I appreciate the help, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** (By managing temporary directory /run/postgresql, /var/run/postgresql)

> Directory */run/postgresql* is a temporary directory. Path
> */var/run/postgresql* is usually a symbolic link to /run/postgresql.
>
> **systemd-tmpfiles** is mechanism to manage such temporary files and directories. **systemd-tmpfiles** creates temporary directories during
> boot and sets their owner, group and permissions.  It may read configuration files in three different locations. Files in
> /etc/tmpfiles.d override files with the same name in
> /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d and /run/tmpfiles.d.

We can create directory */run/postgresql* on the fly at boot time using **systemd-tmpfiles** mechanism by creating postgresql configuration file as below

```
echo "d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -" > /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```

**Solution 2** (By relocating PostgreSQL lock file location)

> Another way to fix the issue is to relocate the PostgreSQL lock file
> location. We can do so by using below query

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET unix_socket_directories='<any-existing-path-with-valid-permissions>, /tmp';
```

Here we can provide any path for PostgreSQL lock file which is already present on the system and have required permissions to manage lock files by postgres user.